# Regex - Get only the integer part

Tags: regex

I could have this: `10%` or `10,00%`. I want to get the number before `%` or `,`.

I'm trying this: `/\d+(?= ?(,\d+)%)/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need backtracking and you do need to put brackets around the piece that you want to capture.

```
/(\d+)(,\d+)?%/
```

In the case of a match, the first match group will be the integer part.

Comment: Yap, you can also read the use case of it here: https://medium.com/@chafid/automated-monitoring-how-to-make-a-sysadmin-life-easier-bbc49754c95d